# Dask groupby-apply followed by join on index without expensive reindexing

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm in a situation in Dask which I would like to get out of, without using a lot of expensive reset_index operations.

I have a task which does a groupby-apply (where the apply returns a dataframe, which has a different size to the input dataframe, in the example this is simulated by the `.head()` and `.tail()` with `reset_index()`).

A operations is carried out on a different dataframe, and these two data frames need to be joined. However, the behavior is not as I had expected. I had expected the dataframe to join only on the dask index, and since dask doesn't implement multi index, I am surprised to see that it joins on both the dask index, and the returned index from the apply:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(
          pd.DataFrame(
                {
                   "group_col": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"], 
                   "val_col": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   "val_col2": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
                }
          ), npartitions=1)

ddf = ddf.set_index("group_col")
out_ddf = ddf.groupby("group_col").apply(lambda _df: _df.head(2).reset_index(drop=True))
out_ddf2 = ddf.groupby("group_col").apply(lambda _df: _df.tail(1).reset_index(drop=True))

out_ddf.join(out_ddf2, rsuffix="_other").compute()
```

Below is the output of the above.

```
             val_col  val_col2  val_col_other  val_col2_other
group_col                                                    
A         0        1         5            3.0             3.0
          1        2         4            NaN             NaN
B         0        4         2            5.0             1.0
          1        5         1            NaN             NaN
```

The desired output (without expensive reshuffling) would be:

```
             val_col  val_col2  val_col_other  val_col2_other
group_col                                                    
A                 1          5             3              3
                  2          4             3              3
B                 4          2             5              1
                  5          1             5              1
```

I have tried various combinations of `.join`/`.merge` calls, and I have been able to achieve the result with:

```
out_ddf.reset_index().merge(out_ddf2.reset_index(), suffixes=(None, "_other"), on="group_col").compute()
```

but I want to do some more operations on the same index later on, so I'm concerned this will hurt the performance, having to jiggle around the index so much.

So I'm looking for solutions which will give the desired result without the overhead of changing the dask indices during the operation, since the data frames are pretty big.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code below might not work in general, but for your example, I would use the fact that the computations are done *within* a group and combine them in a single function that is applied within a group. This avoids merges/data shuffles:

```py
def myfunc(df):
    df1 = df.head(2).reset_index(drop=True)
    df2 = df.tail(1).add_suffix('_other').reset_index(drop=True)
    return df1.join(df2).fillna(method='ffill')
    
out_ddf = ddf.groupby('group_col').apply(myfunc)
print(out_ddf.compute())
```

For more complex workflows, a more nuanced solution will be needed to keep track of data dependencies in each computation.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a helpful way to think about it, I think you're right that it doesn't easily generalize to the case where df1 and df2 are derived from different data frames, but I think it could still be useful in my actual case

Comment: Yes, it might also be possible to combine files upstream via custom delayed...